# Matlab editor won't save function

Tags: matlab, process, editor, save

I have a function named `ProbFinder.m` that runs perfectly. However, when I want to edit it, I receive an error:

```
'Error writing ProbFinder.m.
[Error writes out the file path here] (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)'
```

MATLAB *does* let me save the function as `ProbFinder_2.m`, but if I want to edit it again I receive the same error and must name it `ProbFinder_3.m`, and so forth.

The error doesn't just occur for this function. I've been writing code for a few weeks and it is the same for every file. Restarting MATLAB or the computer doesn't fix it, it always tells me that the file is being used by another process.

I've seen other people with the same error, but their's are caused by a command within the text that tries to access a file, and the error only shows up when they *run* the function, while mine shows up just trying to edit it.

Does anybody have any idea what's causing the problem or a way to fix it?

Comment: Are you using the standard m-file editor of MATLAB? what version of MATLAB do you have? What is your OS?

Comment: Try to change the current folder (which is set to Program Files by default) to somewhere else. I guess you do not have permission to write there (if you are using Windows of course).

Comment: I'm using the standard MATLAB editor, on MATLAB R2013a, on Windows XP. By current folder do you mean the cd in the MATLAB window? Because it's already open to something else, and I'm saving the function somewhere else as well.

Comment: I don't know if it is a factor, but I'm on a shared drive. But I did what you suggested and it still gave me the error that the file was being accessed by another process.

Comment: I assume if you try to work on Desktop, or MyDocument folder, it can say that the problem is related to permission, to do this: 1- exit MATLAB, 2- run MATLAB as administrator, 3- change current directory to Desktop, 4- in MATLAB command-line type : edit filename, it will ask you that you want to create the file. if you had an error post it here.

Comment: are you running more than one matlab instance?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a problem with Windows XP and MATLAB 2013.  I had the same problem when I tried to edit a file in 2013a, but did not have the problem in 2012a.

I have heard that it will also go away on Windows 7 or more recent versions of Windows, but I haven't verified.